# How to get textbox value using jquery when it is store in while loop in php

Tags: php, jquery

There is a probelm in getting a textbox value using jquery it is store in while loop
following is my design code

```
<?php
 while($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 ?>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" class="comment"/>
    <input type="button" name="btncmnt" id="btncmnt" class="btncmnt"/>
 <?php
  }
?>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btncmnt").click(function(){                
            var comment=$(this).val(".comment");
            alert(comment);
            //this will be display only first textbox value
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i click another button of the loop then it will be display first texbox value
please give me ans to get current textbox value
thank in advance

Comment: Your question is incomplete or missing some syntax. like there is no value assigned to textbox within while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that your PHP loop will be creating invalid HTML as you are generating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. As you don't seem to be using it, you should remove it:

```
<?php while($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
  <input type="text" name="comment" class="comment"/>
  <input type="button" name="btncmnt" class="btncmnt"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Your issue is because your use of `val()` is incorrect. You need to first use DOM traversal to find the related `.comment` element, then use the getter of `val()` to retrieve its value, like this:

```
$(".btncmnt").click(function(){                
  var comment = $(this).prev(".comment").val();
  console.log(comment); 
});
```

Comment: how can i get value of the textarea insted of textbox

Comment: In exactly the same way. Get a reference to the element and call `val()`

Comment: i used that bt result will be undefined how can solve that

Comment: In that case you haven't selected the element properly. I'd suggest starting a new question about that as this one is about getting the value from a related `input` and nothing to do with textarea elements